# Loading custom .env file using mocha, dotenv, and esm

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, dotenv

I am running tests with mocha. I have the following config file:

```
{
  "diff": true,
  "extension": [
    "js"
  ],
  "package": "./package.json",
  "reporter": "spec",
  "slow": 75,
  "timeout": 2000,
  "ui": "bdd",
  "recursive": true,
  "exit": true,
  "require": "esm, dotenv/config"
}
```

As all of my code is using import statements, I am using the 'esm' package to get this to work. I am also using the 'dotenv' package to load my .env files.

I just split my .env file for testing, development, and production. However, I cannot get mocha to load the correct .env file. From [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) documentation the is a command line argument (`dotenv_config_path`) that your can use to specify the .env file:

```
$ node -r dotenv/config your_script.js dotenv_config_path=/custom/path/to/your/env/vars
```

I have tried to add this into the config as well as the command line, without success.

Command line:

```
mocha -r dotenv/config -r esm --recursive --exit dotenv_config_path=./env/dev-config.env
```

but get the following error:

```
Error: No test files found: "dotenv_config_path=./env/dev-config.env"
```

However, if there is a `.env` file in the root directory this command works:

```
mocha -r dotenv/config -r esm --recursive --exit
```

So how can I get a custom `.env` file to load?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Ivan's solution, another alternative is to add the configuration directly to your package.json file:

```
"mocha": {
    "env": "dotenv_config_path=./env/test-config.env"   
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. Add this to the mocha options file:

```
"env" : "dotenv_config_path=path/to/env/file"
```

`.mocharc.json` residing in root of project

```
{
  "diff": true,
  "extension": [
    "js"
  ],
  "package": "./package.json",
  "reporter": "nyan",
  "slow": 75,
  "timeout": 5000,
  "ui": "bdd",
  "recursive": true,
  "exit": true,
  "env" : "dotenv_config_path=./env/test-config.env",
  "require": "esm, dotenv/config"
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same need but can't manage to make this solution work and I couldn't find this "env" option in mocha's documentation. Could you please point that out?

Comment: I added it into a file named `.mocharc.json`

Comment: This doesn't work.